# How do I write something in fields with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to srite something in fields with scrapy ?

[For example I want to write my username and password in these fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb5J9.png)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `scrapy.http.FormRequest` class.

Here's the documentation for it: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects